# Can I copy files from NTFS to FAT32, and then open them using a FAT32 OS?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ntfs, fat32

I have a Windows XP operating system disk that is NTFS formatted. The problem is that it is damaged but I can still access some of the files and data, only as a slaved drive. I have a Windows XP operating system that is FAT32 formatted that I can use to store the data on.

Using the NTFS operating system, can I copy the files from the NTFS formatted disk to the FAT32 disk, and when done open them using the FAT32 formatted operating system?

Comment: Are you wondering about disk formats (not a problem; compare to copying files from an ISO cd to your FAT32 or NTFS hard disk, or from a Linux machine to Windows), or about NTFS access rights?

Comment: I need to be able to access the files on the Fat32 operating system once the files are copied and stored from the NTFS formatted disk.

Comment: So you would put them on the FAT32 disk using the NTFS OS, right? And only switch to the FAT32 OS after copying? (If you can use the FAT32 OS to do the copying, then all is fine, obviously.)

Comment: I will use an NTFS operating system to copy them to a FAT32 formatted drive. Then try to use a FAT32 operating system to open them.

Comment: Fat32 stores dates and other meta info differently. A way to not lock up your data in a computer and be dependent on its oprating system is to buy a usb drive and store it there, in NTFS format.

Comment: there's nothing called "NTFS operating system" or "FAT32 operating system"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But be aware that FAT32 has a limited file size: one single file can be no more then 4 GB, while NTFS has a way bigger limit. So if you try to copy a file which has more than 4 GB from NTFS to FAT32, it will fail.

Similar limitations apply to the number of files in a single directory.

Comment: Thanks, now I know why they call these things confusers.

Comment: There are other possible issues: extended file attributes and Alternate Data Streams (ADS) will be stripped out entirely when moving from NTFS to FAT32. Encrypted files will need to be decrypted too. The Windows explorer will warn you about that. NTFS compressed files will be decompressed on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point more issues:

- When copying a folder with hidden attribute (on Windows 10) the hidden attribute is lost, but if it is a file the hidden attribute is also copied.
- When copying a set of .\Folder\HiddenFolder with `xcopy /E .\Folder \AnotherPlace` it does not copy anything hidden, you can use /H to also copy hidden things, but beware it copy the contents of .\Folder, not Folder it self
- To copy all including hidden files/folders and all possible extra data (atributes, ACL, short names, audit) with xcopy, trying with /H /E /K /N /O /X does not work allways well; see `xcopy /?` for all parameters.

Sample of FAIL of `xcopy /E /H ".\MyFolder*" \OtherPlace` when `Folder` is a folder on current directory: It only copy files that start with `MyFolder` on its names, recreating the sub folder structure, but not anything else.

It is a real pain to script file/folders copy with native commands / tools, also on NTFS folder to NTFS folder.

Going to FAT32 there are a lot of things lost, much more than copying on NTFS... and better not think on last states (snapshots of NTFS files), it is so nightmare i start to never use them again.

Another thing not commented is about spare files (files that have a size but not all parts are on disk, only the ones with data on them), the file will be of full size when on FAT32 (no spare possible).

And what about symbolic links that point to other disks, etc. They are not copied (causing a copy fail) if destiny is not available, but if destiny is available the default is to copy all what is there; so you can have a small 2MiB folder with a lot of symbolic links (pointing to ISOs folder, MP3 folder, etc) and the copy han be very huge.

And a large etcetera!

Since you are talking about having WindowXP in NTFS, i must advise you not thinking when copied to FAT32 will even boot, no matter if you fix or not the boot partition (it can be the same as system partition or a different one, also can reside in different disks, etc), there are a lot of things that will not work correctly avoiding it to even boot (will fail at some point after logo and before user logon screen); yes, i know Windows can be installed on FAT32, but after it being on NTFS there are too many things that requiere FIX to put it back on FAT32.

But if it is for a DATA (not system it self) partition, you can copy your MP3, DOC, etc. without much pain, special warning with some applications saved files (and also some games), they requiere NTFS 'extra' things that can not be stored on FAT/FAT32/vFAT/exFAT, etc., only on NTFS.

All this madness happend because not all filesystems have the same funcional, see ZFS (the most powerfull filesystem in terms of redundancy and coherency), i do not know of anyother that uses (at filesystem level) a calculated code for each thing and if that code is wrong it knowns that thing have had a blind change (damaged), in other words, it can detect when the content of a file has got damaged, for explame by a medium physical fail, or to let it more clear, you store some data and let it there for ages, when you read it back and compare with what it was supposed to have, you detect a file has different content than what must have, but no one has written that change, it is the medium that lost that data (magnetic offline change), well ZFS has a method to detect that and if it knows there is another good copy, it automatically replaces the bad one with the bood one.

FAT32 is a very, very simple filsystem, just store plain data and do no care about integrity, NTFS also has no integrity check for file content (i only know of one having such, called ZFS). But ZFS is hard to use, need a lot of RAM to work fast, more than one disk to use it with all the powerfull (as more disk and more ram the better), etc.

Some Linux can be installed on top of a ZFS.

The same NTFS partition can use more than one physical disk, the place where NTFS is put is called dynamic volume (not partition), like software RAID, etc., and the NTFS itself is aware of that, NTFS total size can be dynamic.

FAT32 size can only be one at one time, need repartition to change. NTFS over volumes do not need any repartition, add or remove volumes and NTFS do not need any repartition process.

And there are another things like joints (a folder that combines things that are on more than one folder), it is a way of having a folder that mix the contents of multiple folders, in NTFS but not in FAT*.

Etcetera.

Each filesystem have its own specials things, each OS can use some filesystems (native) and other (with apps or drivers) but i am afraid not all out there, there are tons of different type of filesystems.

I told you about some types that are not Windows native just to make you understand why it is so hard to think about compatibility.

Read info about this tools: SystemRescueCD.iso, GParted, fsArchiver, ...

I know they are Linux, but let you save and backup filesystems while changeing the filesystem type (fsArchiver), but loosing the less possible; again do not change filesystem type for a "system" partition, but you can 'clone' and 'restore' it perfectly.

Special note: If start of windows boot partition is changed, you may need to fix the boot (XP if quite different to Vista and up to 10), read Google, it is a lot to put here all needed to know, but have in mind you need a windows bootable install or repair media. I had fixed a XP with an upper windows boot media (boot code is nt52 for XP, nt60 for Vista up to 10).